# HDD SMART interpretation

Tags: raid, hardware-raid, dell-perc, smart, smartctl

I need your opinion if the drive below is failing.

When I run "smartctl -a /dev/sda -d megaraid,1", 2 errors are posted at the end of the output, stating "Error: WP at LBA". I don't see anything suspicious in the SMART parameters.

Here is the "smartctl -a /dev/sda -d megaraid,1" full output.

This HDD is one of the two HDDs from a RAID 1 (mirrored) hardware configuration, on a Dell H330 controller on a Dell PowerEdge server.

```
smartctl 7.0 2018-12-30 r4883 [x86_64-linux-3.10.0-957.21.3.el7.x86_64] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-18, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     Toshiba 3.5" MG03ACAxxx(Y) Enterprise HDD
Device Model:     TOSHIBA MG03ACA300
Serial Number:    73VCK8GDF
LU WWN Device Id: 5 000039 4ebc82c58
Firmware Version: FL1A
User Capacity:    3,000,592,982,016 bytes [3.00 TB]
Sector Size:      512 bytes logical/physical
Rotation Rate:    7200 rpm
Form Factor:      3.5 inches
Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]
ATA Version is:   ATA8-ACS (minor revision not indicated)
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.0, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 6.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Thu Feb 27 23:05:39 2020 EET
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART Status not supported: ATA return descriptor not supported by controller firmware
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED
Warning: This result is based on an Attribute check.

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x82) Offline data collection activity
                                        was completed without error.
                                        Auto Offline Data Collection: Enabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                                        without error or no self-test has ever
                                        been run.
Total time to complete Offline
data collection:                (  120) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:                    (0x5b) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                                        Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                                        Suspend Offline collection upon new
                                        command.
                                        Offline surface scan supported.
                                        Self-test supported.
                                        No Conveyance Self-test supported.
                                        Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                                        power-saving mode.
                                        Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                                        General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine
recommended polling time:        (   2) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:        ( 510) minutes.
SCT capabilities:              (0x003d) SCT Status supported.
                                        SCT Error Recovery Control supported.
                                        SCT Feature Control supported.
                                        SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 16
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x000b   100   100   050    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  2 Throughput_Performance  0x0005   100   100   050    Pre-fail  Offline      -       0
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0027   100   100   001    Pre-fail  Always       -       8874
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       27
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   100   100   050    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x000b   100   100   050    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  8 Seek_Time_Performance   0x0005   100   100   050    Pre-fail  Offline      -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   068   068   000    Old_age   Always       -       12964
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0033   100   100   030    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       27
191 G-Sense_Error_Rate      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       6
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       25
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       42
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       31 (Min/Max 11/48)
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0030   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
220 Disk_Shift              0x0002   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
222 Loaded_Hours            0x0032   068   068   000    Old_age   Always       -       12994
223 Load_Retry_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
224 Load_Friction           0x0022   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
226 Load-in_Time            0x0026   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       103
240 Head_Flying_Hours       0x0001   100   100   001    Pre-fail  Offline      -       0

SMART Error Log Version: 1
ATA Error Count: 2
        CR = Command Register [HEX]
        FR = Features Register [HEX]
        SC = Sector Count Register [HEX]
        SN = Sector Number Register [HEX]
        CL = Cylinder Low Register [HEX]
        CH = Cylinder High Register [HEX]
        DH = Device/Head Register [HEX]
        DC = Device Command Register [HEX]
        ER = Error register [HEX]
        ST = Status register [HEX]
Powered_Up_Time is measured from power on, and printed as
DDd+hh:mm:SS.sss where DD=days, hh=hours, mm=minutes,
SS=sec, and sss=millisec. It "wraps" after 49.710 days.

Error 2 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 12901 hours (537 days + 13 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 41 10 0e fb 74 40  Error: WP at LBA = 0x0074fb0e = 7666446

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  61 08 00 48 7a e0 40 00  42d+20:47:35.187  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
  61 08 20 58 89 8a 40 00  42d+20:47:35.187  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
  61 10 20 48 89 8a 40 00  42d+20:47:35.187  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
  61 08 20 48 7a e0 40 00  42d+20:47:35.183  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
  61 08 20 40 89 8a 40 00  42d+20:47:35.183  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED

Error 1 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 12901 hours (537 days + 13 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 41 00 0e fb 74 40  Error: WP at LBA = 0x0074fb0e = 7666446

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  61 10 10 18 94 de 40 00  42d+20:47:32.312  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 08 00 fc 74 40 00  42d+20:47:32.311  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 00 00 fb 74 40 00  42d+20:47:32.311  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 00 00 fa 74 40 00  42d+20:47:32.284  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 00 00 f9 74 40 00  42d+20:47:32.264  READ FPDMA QUEUED

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
No self-tests have been logged.  [To run self-tests, use: smartctl -t]

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.
```

**Later edit 1:**

I have checked also the iDRAC on the PowerEdge server and in the Storage menu > Summary > Recently Logged Storage Events I have found the event coresponding to the occurance of the 2 SMART errors.

The Event States: "A disk media error on Disk 1 in Backplane 1 of RAID Controller in Slot 1 was corrected during recovery". Please find below the screenshot.

[Image from iDRAC > Storage menu > Summary > Recently Logged Storage Events](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QIHFr.png)

**Later edit 2:**

After a few days, Current_Pending_Sector increased to 1 for a few hours and then decreased to 0.

Reallocated_Sector_Ct, Reallocated_Event_Count and Offline_Uncorrectable remained 0 all the time.

Also another error appeared in SMART error log: "Error: UNC at LBA".

Although, no other errors appeared in the iDRAC.

We decided to change the drive with a new one, because we no longer trusted this drive.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two logged errors state that your HDD failed read/writing a specific LBA. However, no `Reallocated_Sector_Ct / Reallocated_Event_Count / Current_Pending_Sector` where logged, which seems to indicate no problem on platter side.

However, this does **not** means that you can discard the errors as software-induced ones: after all some LBA were not read/written properly, so you have a *real* issue. When such kind of errors pop-up without a corresponding bad sector, they can often be caused by:

- bad SATA/power cables
- bad power supply
- too much vibrations.

On a proper PowerEdge server, you should not have cable problems (ie: you are using a SATA backplan). While occasional issues can occur, they are quite rare.

On the other side, you have a non-zero `G-Sense_Error_Rate`, so maybe the failed read/write is related to a strong vibration of the server/disk.

I would monitor both SATA and `dmesg` logs to be sure that the issue does not recur. If you see it again, please take note of the affected LBA range and compare it with the one above (`LBA = 0x0074fb0e = 7666446`): if it continue to be the same, you have a genuinely bad sector which for some reason is not reported by SMART data (a relatively common behavior on consumer disks, albeit surprising for an enterprise HDD).

**UPDATE:** based on your iDRAC logs, it seems that a *Media Error* was corrected using the value stored in the other mirror leg by a Patrol Read. This really seems a genuine bad block; however, the fact that the relative SMART counters where not increased is puzzling. In the past I saw a disk which reallocated sectors only when a read/write error was reported *twice* for the affected sector, but it would be strange for a Toshiba enterprise disk.

Another possible explanation is that something (maybe a strong vibration) caused a bad/unaligned/torn write which made a sector unreadable. However, as that sector was not really damaged, it was overwritten successfully by the Patrol Read without any reallocation happening.

Finally, it can be a genuine case of bitrot: the written data did non match the HDD internal ECC checksum. In these cases, HDDs are designed to return a read error; however, this does not explain the *write* error reported above.

Anyway, **occasional** media correction are to be expected. However, as stated above, I would monitor the situation and substitute the disk if such reports become more frequent.

Comment: Thank you for your complete answer. I have checked also the iDRAC on the PowerEdge server and in the Storage menu > Summary > Recently Logged Storage Events I have found the event coresponding to the occurance of the 2 SMART errors. The Event states: "A disk media error on Disk 1 in Backplane 1 of RAID Controller in Slot 1 was corrected during recovery". What this may mean in the context?

Comment: I have updated the post with the additional print screen and information from iDRAC.

Comment: @Alexandru thanks for the iDRAC logs. I've updated my answer.

Comment: I just wanted to come back with an update, because of your complete answer. After a few days, Current_Pending_Sector increased to 1 for a few hours and then decreased to 0. Reallocated_Sector_Ct, Reallocated_Event_Count and Offline_Uncorrectable remained 0 all the time. Also another error appeared in SMART error log: "Error: UNC at LBA". Although, no other errors appeared in the iDRAC. So, we decided to change the drive with a new one.

Comment: Thanks for the update. This confirm your disk does not correctly increase/report reallocated sectors.

Answer (score 1):

Judging by:

```
Reallocated_Sector_Ct   100   0
Reallocated_Event_Count 100   0
Current_Pending_Sector  100   0
```

Your HDD is fine. No reallocated sectors or pending to be reallocated. Practically, no suspect sector has been detected.

The WP error (which means write-protect) may have various non-physical causes (software-related).

Therefore, your HDD is not failing.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.